# SuiteCommerce Advance: Create Custom Service to fetch the custom record from Netsuite's backend to backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, netsuite, suitecommerce

I have custom record created in netsuite's backend named Webstore Landing Data. Record is having below structure & columns

```
Record Id: customrecord_webstore_category_landing
Coloumns:
    i. custrecord_collection_name
    ii. custrecord_collection_sub_category
    iii. custrecord_collection_url
```

And need to create service to fetch this record on backbone view. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Good question. This is the most important and required thing in SCA check below details-->

**Note: Below steps is for SuiteCOmmerce Advance Vision(2016-17) release**

You need to created below things-->

```
i.  SuiteScript Model 
ii. SuiteScript Service  
iii.JavaScript Model     
iv. JavaScript view  
v.  JavaScript Template
vi. Update distro.json
```

1. Create custom folder(our custom module) under custom folder as

   Modules/custom/Categorylanding@1.0.0
2. Create SuiteScript folder under above module
3. Create SuiteScript Service under 'SuiteScript' Folder as below-->

**FileName & Path:**    Modules/custom/Categorylanding@1.0.0/SuiteScript/Categorylanding.ServiceController.js

Code:

```
 define(
    'Categorylanding.ServiceController'
,   [
        'ServiceController'
    ,   'Categorylanding.Model'
    ]
,   function(
        ServiceController
    ,   Categorylanding
    )
    {
        'use strict';

        return ServiceController.extend({

            name: 'Categorylanding.ServiceController'

           , get: function()
            {
               return Categorylanding.get();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

4. Create SuiteScript Model under SuiteScript folder as below-->

**FileName & Path:**
Modules/custom/Categorylanding@1.0.0/SuiteScript/Categorylanding.Model.js

**Code:**

```
define('Categorylanding.Model',
  [
  'SC.Model'
  ],
  function (SCModel) {
    return SCModel.extend({
      name: 'Categorylanding',
      get: function()
      {
        var filters = new Array();
        var columns = new Array();
        columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_collection_name');
        columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_collection_url');
        var results = nlapiSearchRecord('customrecord_webstore_category_landing', null, filters, columns);

        var results_ = JSON.stringify(results);
        return results_;
      }
    });
  }
)
```

5. Created ns package file

**Filename & Path:**

Modules/custom/Categorylanding@1.0.0/ns.package.json

**Code:**

```
{
    "gulp": {
        "javascript": [
            "JavaScript/*"
        ],
        "ssp-libraries": [
            "SuiteScript/*.js"
        ],
        "autogenerated-services": {
            "Categorylanding.Service.ss": "Categorylanding.ServiceController"
        },
        "templates": [
            "Templates/*"
        ],
        "images": [
            "Images/*"
        ],
        "sass": [
            "Sass/*.scss"
        ],
        "configuration": [
            "Configuration/*.json"
        ]
    }
}
```

6. Update distro. json file as below

add your module under modules section as

```
"custom/Categorylanding": "1.0.0",
```

and dependencies in

```
"ssp-libraries": {
            "entryPoint": "SCA",
            "dependencies": [

  "CategoryLanguage.ServiceController",
   "CategoryLanguage.Model", 
],
```

7. Deploy your code and once this is done you can able to see your data when in return call, you can call your service as below

   http://yoursite.com/sca-dev-vinson/services/Categorylanding.Service.ss?c=4515330
8. Now the remaining part is how you can get this data on backbone view, to do this go to your view where you want this data

Before that create Javascript model under Same folder as below

**Filename & Path** :

Modules/custom/Categorylanding@1.0.0/JavaScript/Categorylanding.Model.js

**Code:**

```
define('Categorylanding.Model',
  [
  'Backbone',
  'underscore'
  ],
  function (Backbone, _) {
    return Backbone.Model.extend(
    {
        url: function()
        { var  urlRoot = _.getAbsoluteUrl('services/Categorylanding.Service.ss');
            return urlRoot;
      }
    });
  }
);
```

9. Once this is done, you can call above javascript model on any view/router file to get the record data on backbone view

Define mode and use below code

```
    var collection = new CategorylandingModel();
    var view = new BrowseView({
                            translator: translator
                            ,   translatorConfig: self.translatorConfig
                            ,   application: self.application
                            ,   collection: collection
});

collection.fetch().done(function(data)  //again fetch Instagram service
                        {
                            console.log(data)                           //your service data will log here

                        });
```

10. Now you can able to access your data on BrowseView(){} as

**var recorddata = this.collection.attributes;**

console.log(recorddata);

and Pass it handlebar. That's it.

Let me know if you want any help....

Comment: This is Awesome Details, I'll let you know after Implementation. Thanks.